# Use all classes of a folder

Tags: php, symfony

I created a service in Symfony 4 which enables me to recover the name of each class PHP of a file and instantiate each class thanks to a loop.

But I have this error which is logical because I don't use it “use” for each class :

> Attempted to load class "MyClass" from the global namespace. Did
>   you forget a "use" statement for "App\Service\Adapter\MyClass"?

I would like that each file of my file is used automatically in my service. Is this possible?

My code :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Service\Factory;

use App\Service\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use function dump;
use function explode;
use function scandir;

/**
 * Class ArticleFactory
 *
 * @package App\Service\Factory
 */
class ArticleFactory
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    protected $entityManager;
    protected $pathService;

    /**
     * ArticleFactory constructor.
     *
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     * @param $pathService
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, $pathService)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->pathService = $pathService;
    }

    public function adapters(): void
    {
        $scandir = scandir($this->pathService . '/Adapter', SCANDIR_SORT_NONE);
        $adapters = [];

        foreach ($scandir as $key => $value) {
            if ($value !== '.' && $value !== '..' && $value !== 'AdapterAbstract.php' && $value !== 'AdapterInterface.php') {
                $cuttedString = explode('.php', $value);
                $className = $cuttedString[0];

                $adapters[] = new $className($this->entityManager);
            }
        }

        foreach ($adapters as $adapter) {
            if ($adapter instanceof AdapterInterface) {
                $adapter->rss();
                $article = $adapter->adapt();

                foreach ($article as $item) {
                    $this->entityManager->persist($item);
                }
            }
        }
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

I tested this but it doesn't work :

```
use App\Service\Adapter;
```

And :

```
use App\Service\Adapter\*;
```

And :

```
$className = '\\'.$cuttedString[0];
$adapters[] = new $className($this->entityManager);
```

Comment: Maybe it would work by instantiating classes with the full namespace `App\Service\Adapter\MyClass` instead of only the class name.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Update your question with the namespace from one of your adapter classes and we might have a better chance at guessing the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is somewhat misleading; `use` statements are a shorthand form for the class name *in a particular source file*, and are purely for convenience; you never *need* a `use` statement, and they don't make any difference to class names referenced dynamically like you're doing here.

Your actual problem is that when you find a file `Foo.php`, you are trying to load a class called `Foo` (or, in one of your attempted fixes, `\Foo`), when the actual name of the class is `App\Service\Adapter\Foo`.

The fix is therefore simple: use the full class name, with the namespace prefixed:

```
$className = 'App\Service\Adapter\\' . $cuttedString[0];
```

(Note the last `\` has to be escaped as `\\`, because even in a single-quoted string, `\'` acts as an escaped quote mark so that you can write `'foo\'s bar'`.)

Comment: `'App\Service\Adapter\\'` Should it be `'App\Service\Adapter\'` instead?

Comment: @A.L No, that's deliberate; see added note.

Comment: So we only have to escape the last backslash when there are several backslashes in a string between single quotes? Edit: sadly, the answer is yes https://3v4l.org/OoJ82

Comment: @A.L You need to escape a backslash if it is the last character of a string, regardless of what else is in the string. If you write `'foo \'`, the `\'` is considered part of the string (a literal `'`), so PHP will carry on looking for the `'` that marks the end of the string, as in the `'foo\'s bar'` example I used in my answer. If you write `'foo \ bar'`, you don't have that problem, because `\ ` (backslash+ space) has no special meaning in a single-quoted string.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Should't it be `\App\Service\Adapter...`? Otherwise it would be assumed that `App` is in the current directory rather then the global namespace.

Comment: @qooplmao Not in the context of a string like this I believe; the logic seems to be that the "current namespace", like the aliases from "use" statements, apply to the current file, at compile time, whereas a string like this is resolved at run time, and is treated as its own context.

Answer (score 0):

If a file (or class) does not use any namespace than it will be placed in the global namespace. You can instantiate those classes with a backslash () as prefix. For example:

```
$myClass = new \MyClass();
$datetime = new \DateTime();
```